# What does "return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)" error message mean in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, runtime

I was intending to use recursion instead of  for loop to print out some numbers (for no reason except playing around) so I came to this code and when I implement it, it works perfectly for all values of i's up to 980 where it implements the code correctly but after the end of the implementation it gives

***Traceback***
***(lots of stuff)***

***File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1342, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)***

***RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object***

Additionally, for values of i greater than 980, it does not print all of the values, It just prints the first 980 loops and then crashes giving the same message.

I suspect that this is related to space and time required to do the implementation and has to do with the structure of how python works rather than an error of the code but I'm no expert in neither python nor programming so I'd like to understand why this happens?

```
def cout(i):
   if i==0:
          print(0)
   else:
          print(i)
          i-=1
          cout(i)
```

Comment: You are having something which is called a *stack overflow*. This is what happens when you have a too deep recursion.

Comment: Why are you using recursion for this? It's a simple loop. Python is not a functional language and does not do tail call optimisation.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, just playing around and seeing how python will deal with that. If I were to write a real code, I'd definitely use a for loop instead of recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not** a stack overflow as @Some_programmer_dude mentions but a security to avoid stack overflow. You can change the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit`, but doing so is dangerous -- the standard limit is a little conservative, but Python stackframes can be quite big.

You should rewrite your algorithm without recursion. As you may know, every recursive  algorithm can be transformed into an equivalent iterative one.

Comment: This is nice, I will search for "stack overflow" to know what is that. I know that I can do that by a simple for loop but I was just playing around. Thanx :)